# Moderator meta notification broken for employees

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, top-bar

Moderators get notifications of new Meta posts on their site, which is totes rad and I've loved it from when I was a moderator.

Right now, though, when I click on a link from the mod box, it doesn't point to the meta post. It's missing the `meta.` in the URL, which causes it to instead point to the corresponding post on the main site with the same ID. So for example, trying to [catch this Meta Arqade question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8428/other-media-tangentally-related-to-video-games) instead links to [this Arqade answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8097/does-solomons-digging-have-any-effect-on-gameplay/8428#8428).

I checked with a handful of other moderators so it appears that this might not affect everyone. And I've never heard any moderator complain about it... so I'm led to believe this is possibly employee only.

Comment: As an employee you're supposed to be navigating to meta _with your mind_, after detecting a slight change in the universe when a new meta post is written. Read the manual, I'm pretty sure that's in section 7,826.

Comment: If I upvote this will it get us moderator meta notifications back?